# Number generated randomly ? and problem here with the 2nd if statement?

Tags: java

it is show that error in the 2nd If statement why???

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Test 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("T : " + Tfun());
   }

public static String Tfun()
{
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
    int T = 1+r.nextInt(10);


    if(T >= 1 && T <= 5)
        Integer.toString(T);
        return "Fast_Plod";

    if(T >= 6 && T <= 7)
        Integer.toString(T);
        return "Slow_Plod";
  }
}
```

how to fix that? what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Place braces around both lines of each `if` block.  Unlike Python, indenting means nothing to the Java compiler.

Comment: Or get rid of `Integer.toString(T);` as it is pointless.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why I always use brackets, even if only one line of code follows.

Comment: i check with brackets also it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this block (And the other `if` block):

```
 if(T >= 1 && T <= 5)
    Integer.toString(T);
    return "Fast_Plod";
```

You forgot brackets, so the return is always executed, resulting in the rest of the code in the method being dead code (code that can never be reached). Indentation means nothing in java, so you have to specify that the `return` statement is within the `if` block by surrounding it, and all the other lines that should be in the if block, with brackets. Also the lines `Integer.toString(T);` do nothing. Lastly, `T` can be a number greater than `7`, so you must specify a `return` for this too.

To fix this simply add brackets:

```
if(T >= 1 && T <= 5) {
    return "Fast_Plod";
}
if(T >= 6 && T <= 7) {
    return "Slow_Plod";
}
else {
    return "";  //return what you want to return if it's > 7
}
```

Comment: i check with brackets also it didnt work

Comment: @ShaheerAhmad What error are you getting?

Comment: @ShaheerAhmad Because it does not handle the case when `T` is greater than 7.

Comment: I want to return T (int type) as a String from that function

Comment: @ShaheerAhmad Then why do you have the `if` statements at all? Why not just `return Integer.toString(T);`?

Comment: because i generated random number and if that number is in that condition so it would return it.

Comment: @ShaheerAhmad You want to return the String representation of `T` or a `String` based on the value of `T`? (i.e. if `T` is within a range return "Hello", or within a different range "Goodbye")

Answer (score 0):

To add on to GBlodgett's answer you can get away with not putting brackets around the block to be executed in an `if` statement if it is only one statement (only one `;`). Java will execute the first statement after the `if` and then carry on as if the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("T : " + Tfun());
    }

    public static String Tfun() {
        SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
        int T = 1+r.nextInt(10);

        if(T >= 1 && T <= 5) {
            Integer.toString(T);
            return "Fast_Plod";
        }else if(T >= 6 && T <= 7) {
            Integer.toString(T);
            return "Slow_Plod";
        }else {
            return "your return value.";
        }
    }
}
```